# Induced EMF of different wire shapes?

Tags: voltage

Given the following diagram:

[image]

Both conductors are moving at the same velocity, and the same direction, and are in the same magnetic field. They should induce the same ϵ even when their shapes are different?

ϵ = -vBL , my assumption that they should be the same.

My apologizes for the simplistic diagram, I don't have the proper programs to draw this a bit better.

Edit:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltages will be the same theoretically because the shape of the more complex coil, and the field it is moving in, has the same effect as the simpler coil i.e. all the horizontal elements are irrelevant to picking up emf.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19295/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-induced-emf-of-different-wire-shapes).